# how to apply SoftDeletable on child entity using symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, soft-delete

i want to get users with their posts(not soft-deleted)
the user has many posts

```
 return $this->em->getRepository(Users::class)->find($userId);
```

when i get the result i the posts with deletedAt!=null are returned , but when i get only list of posts ,the deleted one are not returned.

```
return $this->em->getRepository(Posts::class)->findAll();
```

so i need to apply this filteron child entity when i get them from User

Comment: Both entities configured as softDeletable ? Could you post your annotations and relations ?

Comment: yes both entities are configured as softDeletable, when i execute 
return $this->em->getRepository(Posts::class)->findAll(); i get a correct result

Comment: @Feras Kariba, Ok. There are such tings like `cascade={"remove"}` and `orphanRemoval=true`  and `Criteria`. To find out more and identify the problem, I'd like to take a look at your annotations for 
`private $post;` in your User entity and `private $user;` in your Post entity

Comment: On User entity    
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Posts::class, mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *  @Serializer\Groups({"public","payment_agreements_admin","offer_student"})
     */
    private $posts;

Comment: On Post entity

   /**
     * @var \Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Serializer\Groups({"public","payment_agreement_slices_admin"})
     */
    private $user;

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using simple `find()` and `findBy()` method, I think, the quickest solution would be to use `Criteria` (`\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`) in your getter for Post from User.

I assume you have something like that:

```php
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Posts::class, mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
 * 
 */ 
private $posts;
....

/**
 * @return Posts[]|Collection
 */
public function getPosts(): Collection
{
  return $this->posts;
}
```

So you could update you `getPosts()` method like:

```php
/**
 * @param bool $ignoreDeleted
 * 
 * @return Posts[]|Collection
 */
public function getPosts(bool $ignoreDeleted = true)
{
  if($ignoreDeleted)
  {
     $crit = Criteria::create()->andWhere( Criteria::expr()->isNull('deletedAt') );
     // $crit->orderBy(['createdAt' => Criteria::DESC]); // newest first
     return $this->posts->matchin($crit);
  }

  return $this->posts;
}
```

With that you have more control. If you'd like to 'skip' those filtering, simply call the method with `$someUser->getPosts(false);`

The same applies for twig

```
{% for posts in user.post %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

would automagically call `getPost()` on `$user` and if you, for some reason, needs all just be explicit `{% for allPosts in user.getPosts(fasle) %}`

Comment: Thanks  , but in my case i use query builder to get users with their posts, in case to get one user i use the getter and it works fine , but in my cas i need to get all users with their posts